# Invariant to restrict function overriding in Hack PHP

Tags: php, invariants, hacklang

I have a base class in PHP Hack with a function:

```
// This method is used to return just one Apple Type
protected static function Apple(): AppleType {
    return AppleType;
}
```

Now I have two types of classes - one using a base trait, one doesn't.

The trait has the below function:

```
// This method is used to return more than one Apple Type
protected static function Apples(): keyset[AppleType] {
    return keyset[AppleType];
}
```

The child classes which don't use this trait can override the base class Apple() method. But the classes which do use the trait, must override Apples() and not Apple().

Now I want to provide an invariant exception:

Something like:

```
invariant(Apple() is not overridden in this class, 'Class must override Apples() and not Apple()');
```

i.e. invariant to provide enforcement that a class using trait must not be able to override base class's Apple() and throws exception during runtime.

Please help me in writing this invariant. I tried many things, but somehow it doesn't work right.

Comment: Traits shouldn't create requirements unless it uses them. You _could_ force subclasses to implement an interface with an `apples()` signature via [trait and interface requirements](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/classes/trait-and-interface-requirements), but _only if_ methods in that trait use the method `apples()`. Should `apples()` be abstract in your example? Can you share more about why you want to enforce this invariant?

Answer (score 0):

You could define a class with a `final` method, and require that trait users extends that class.

```
enum AppleType: int {
  Fresh = 1;
  Stale = 2;
}

class Overridable {
  protected static function Apple(): AppleType {
    return AppleType::Fresh;
  }
}

class MustUseApples extends Overridable {
  <<__Override>>
  final protected static function Apple(): AppleType {
    return parent::Apple();
  }
}

trait MyTrait {
  require extends MustUseApples;

  protected static function Apples(): keyset<AppleType> {
    return keyset[AppleType::Stale];
  }
}
```

However, if you want to require that trait users must provide an implementation of `Apples`, you should probably make it an abstract method on `MustUseApples`.